# what is wrong with this understanding of contour intergration?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

**problem statement:**

> integrate $f(z)=2$ over a curve $C$ in an anticlockwise sense,  where $C$ is a semi-circular arc centered at the origin with radius $2$.

**math representation:**

$$
\int_C f(z) \, dz ;\qquad 
f(z)=2 ;\qquad 
C: \space \lvert z \rvert = 2 \qquad 
\tag{1}
$$

**analytically,**

the *integral* $(1)$ is a rectangular area whose length = *length of curve C* $= 2\pi$ and height $ = 2$ (because $f(z) = \mathrm{constant}$)

[image: simpe line integral over a curve]

$\therefore$ *integral* $(1)$ evaluates to $2\pi \cdot 2 = 4\pi$

**using complex integration,** with curve $C$ represented as parameter
$$
\int_C f(z) \, dz = \int_0^\pi f\bigl(C(t)\bigr) C'(t) \, dt
$$
where $C(t) = 2e^{it} \quad \implies \quad C'(t) = 2ie^{it}$
$$
\int_0^\pi 2 \cdot (e^{it})^0 \cdot 2ie^{it} \, dt 
= 4i \left[\frac{e^{it}}{i}\right]_0^\pi = -8
$$

Question
why are they not equal?

Comment: Because $dz$ is not the same as the arclength measure $ds$. It is instead $dx+idy$. (A more extreme example happens with a closed curve, where the integral of a constant will be just zero.)

Comment: $\int_Cdz$ does not compute the length of $C$. Some people might use $\int_C|dz|$ to denote the integral that finds the length. Speaking loosely, that first integral cares way too much about the direction one is traveling in, when to compute the length all it should care about is how far it travels.

Comment: Notice the notation @Ian used: If $dz = dx + idy$, then $|dz| = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$, which is what we usually denote as $ds$, i.e. arc-length. Again, this is a rather loose use of notation.

Comment: @ian the integral in question is a line integral, so they must be same. Here the function that i chose is analytic, so maybe the path independence of analytic function will come into play?. Does it mean the answer will for non analytic functions.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC i think that's only because $\int_C dz$ has $f(z)=1$ which is analytic. So the curve does not matter because of path independence.

Comment: Well, your title said "contour integral", you wrote $dz$, and you also wrote your function as a function of $z$, not $(x, y)$. All three of these are asking for a complex integral - which is *not* the same thing as a line integral, and which you shouldn't expect to yield the same value.

Comment: So to answer the title question, what's wrong with this understanding of contour integration is thinking that it is a variety of line integral, and it's not. They might look superficially the same, but they are two different things. In fact, you've actually just proved it by providing a counter example.